# Configure app for Ipad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Converting to a Universal App in xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580935/converting-to-a-universal-app-in-xcode-4)
>   [iPhone - How to transform an iPhone only app to universal app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223032/iphone-how-to-transform-an-iphone-only-app-to-universal-app)

Hi,
   I have created an iphone app. Is there anyway to change it into an ipad app? Basically, how to change an iphone app into a universal app when the app is already finished in Xcode?
THanks

Answer (score 1):

You might start by reading the [Creating a Universal Application](http://tinyurl.com/4xwlty3) section of the Application Programming Guide.